# ¿Como solucionar el detalle al hacer una consulta me muestra como false o sin datos?

Tags: php

Estoy creando una aplicación con Android y trabjando con PHP para almacenar los registros en la base de datos, antes de insertar los datos quiero realizar una consulta para validar si hay la cantidad adecuada de productos en la tabla de inventario del campo stock y compararlo cuando se ingrese en el campo cantidad si es mayor con lo que hay en stock.

El problema es que creo que no me esta trayendo los datos ya que al hacer pruebas ya sea una cantidad menor o superior me arroja el alerta que no hay suficiente stock, poro si hay cantidad de stock en tabla de inventario.

**Tabla de inventario**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Salida.php**

```
<?php

  include('conexion.php');

  $codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
  $factura = $_POST["factura"];
  $fechaSalida = $_POST["fechaSalida"];
  $cantidad = $_POST["cantidad"];


 $validacion = "SELECT inv_stock FROM inventario WHERE inv_pro_codigo = $codigo";

  $result = $mysql->query($validacion);
  
 if ($cantidad > $result) {
 echo "No hay cantidad suficiente en stock";
    
 }
 $sql = "INSERT INTO salida (codigo,factura,fechaSalida,cantidad)
         VALUES('$codigo','$factura','$fechaSalida','$cantidad')";

 $resultado = $mysql->query($sql);
 if ($resultado) {
    echo "El dato se ha insertado correctamente";
 } 

 $mysql->close();

?>
```

Comment: hicistes un var_dump o dd de result para ver si esta extrayendo correctamente los datos?

Comment: @HeynerMartinez si ya lo hice esto me lanza `NULL object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: Después de ```$result = $mysql->query($validacion);``` te falta obtener los datos, esto lo puedes hacer con ```$fila = $result->fetch_assoc();``` y luego para comparar haces ```if ($cantidad > $fila['inv_stock']) {}```

Comment: En el primer query el campo `inv_pro_codigo` es VARCHAR por lo que esa línea la parte `inv_pro_codigo = $codigo` debería ser `inv_pro_codigo = '$codigo'`

Comment: @DBE me sale el siguiente error `Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in`  pero lo cambie por esto `$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc();`  y salio lo siguiente `Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given` y con `var_dump` me sale NULL NULL

Comment: Es porque tienes algún error en tu sentencia por eso el error, para ver el error mejor podrías hacer ```$result = $mysql->query($validacion) or die($mysql->error);```, de todas formas prueba cambiar como te han mencionado esa línea```inv_pro_codigo = '$codigo'```, aun así te deje una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es mejor ya que veo que estas aprendiendo `PHP` es que uses [sentencia preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) y así ya aprendes bien y tendrás más seguridad en tu aplicación.

El error en tu ejemplo es que te falto obtener una fila de resultado como un array asociativo, algo como: `$fila = $result->fetch_assoc();`

`$fila['inv_stock']` sería la cantidad obtenido desde la Base de datos.

También como ha comentado @aeportugal, te faltaba las *comillas simples* al parámetro que pasas que es una cadena `inv_pro_codigo = '$codigo'`

Te dejo un ejemplo con sentencias preparada para así orientarte.

**Posible ejemplo:**

```
// Si esta definido el formulario
if (isset($_POST)) : 
    // Conexión
    include('conexion.php');
    // Obtienes datos desde el formulario
    $codigo = $_POST["codigo"] ?: '';
    $factura = $_POST["factura"] ?: '';
    $fechaSalida = $_POST["fechaSalida"] ?: '';
    $cantidad = $_POST["cantidad"] ?: '';
    // Iniciamos stock en 0
    $stock = 0;

    // Sentencia
    $validacion = "SELECT inv_stock FROM inventario WHERE inv_pro_codigo = ?";
    // Creamos sentencia preparada
    $stmt = $mysql->prepare($validacion);
    // Agrega variables a una sentencia preparada como parámetros
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$codigo); // s supongamos que codigo es string y no int
    // Ejecutamos sentencia
    $stmt->execute();
    // Vincula variables a una sentencia preparada para el almacenamiento de resultados
    $stmt->bind_result($stock);
    // Obtiene los resultados de una sentencia preparadas en las variables vinculadas
    $stmt->fetch();
    // Cerramos sentencia
    $stmt->close();
    
    // Comprobacion del stock
    if ($cantidad > $stock) {
        echo "No hay cantidad suficiente en stock";
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO salida (codigo,factura,fechaSalida,cantidad)
             VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $mysql->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('sssi',$codigo,$factura,$fechaSalida,$cantidad); // s = string , i = int
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt) {
          echo "El dato se ha insertado correctamente con ID: {$stmt->insert_id}";
        } 

        $stmt->close();
    }
endif;
```

Comment: Me sirvió mucho la forma de trabajar con sentencias preparadas, anteriormente ya había trabajado con PDO y sentencias preparadas en un sistema web sencillo, pero esta vez se me estaba dificultado al implementarlas en una aplican móvil, pero muchas gracias DBE.

Comment: @H-jAngel de nada amigo, me alegro que te haya valido, si te ha servido esta respuesta, puedes marcarla como valida, y así puede ayudar a otros, un saludo.